# How bracket notation in javascript access the property of an object?

Tags: javascript

Consider below example:

```
a={
  'firstProperty': "first", 
  'secondProperty':"second"
};
console.log(a[[[["firstProperty"]]]]);
```

by using multiple bracket notation i am able to access the firstProperty. How bracket notation is accessing this property??

Answer (score 2):

You are using a nested array and by using a non string or symbol as value, the value is converted to string.

```js
console.log([[["firstProperty"]]].toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Because what you provide as the key in a property accessor expression is converted to string if it isn't a Symbol or a string. `console.log(a[[[["firstProperty"]]]]);` uses an array of arrays as the property name in the accessor expression. Since that isn't a Symbol, it's converted to string. When you convert your array to string, you get the string `"firstProperty"` because that's how `Array.prototype.toString` works:

```js
console.log(String([[["firstProperty"]]]));
```

...and `"firstProperty"` correctly identifies one of the properties in the object, so the property accessor expression gives you the value of that property.

Using an array like that is unnecessary. Just use

```
console.log(a["firstProperty"]);
```

or

```
console.log(a.firstProperty);
```